# How to get count of rows returned from nested and WHERE IN used query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count

```
SELECT kullaniciNick,
       kullaniciAdi,
       kullaniciSoyadi
FROM panelkullanicilari
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT user_id
     FROM proje_ekip
     WHERE proje_id=11)
ORDER BY kullaniciSoyadi
```

at the query i need the count of rows to check if it is over 6 or less. 
When i used the COUNT(*) i got an error message. That said it must used with GROUP BY.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT kullaniciNick,
       kullaniciAdi,
       kullaniciSoyadi,
       count(*) -- Added this line
FROM panelkullanicilari
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT user_id
     FROM proje_ekip
     WHERE proje_id=11)
GROUP BY 1,2,3 -- Added this line
ORDER BY kullaniciSoyadi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a result, and it's size in one query.
Use 2 queries. First one will give you the size of result and second one will be the result. The First query, should be like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM panelkullanicilari
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT user_id
     FROM proje_ekip
     WHERE proje_id=11)
```

the second one , is just like the query you wrote above.